# Smooth saturation function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

I need a function similar to 
$$Saturation(x)=min(max(x, -1), 1)$$
except for I need it to be smooth with no jump in its derivatives. It seems $arctan$ is not a good candidate since I need it to keep the $|Saturation(x)-x|<0.02$ as far as $|x|<0.9$ while $arctan$ gives me a big error. 
[image: saturation]

The function must be identical around $x=0$ and almost flat after $x=1$.

So, the requirements of the function are:

$$f'(0)=1$$
$$f(0)=0$$
$$f'(1)\thickapprox0$$
$$f(0.90)=0.88$$
$$|f(x)|<1$$
$$|f'(x)| \leqslant 1$$
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} , \exists \frac{d^n}{dx} f(x)$$

Can anybody suggest me such a function?

Comment: You could smooth out the transitions with a piece of a sine curve.

Comment: or with a polynomial.  What you you mean with almost flat? With a polynomial of nth order you can easily solve $f'(0)=1$, $f(0)=0$ $f(1)=1$, $f'(1)=0$ $f(-1)=-1$, $f'(-1)=0$. Another possibility is to construct a piecewise linear approximation and use a convolution to flatten it out

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1, the problem with polynomials is that they do not keep the conditions for the whole (-inf,+inf) range.

Comment: @Regret, thank you for the answer, however could you tell me how to implement it in a way to have derivative from any order on the whole real number range?

Comment: @barej: My apologies, I missed that part.

Comment: Would it be too tricky to use a mollifier?

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides, would you please explain more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Logistic Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Derivative) should do the trick. I set up the version below to capture some of your requirements.

$$\text{Sat}(x)=\frac{2}{1+e^{-2x}}-1$$

Note: $\text{Sat}'(0)=1,|\text{Sat}'(x)|\leq 1, |\text{Sat}(x)|\leq 1,\text{Sat}(0.9)\approx 0.72, \text{Sat}(0)=0$ and all derivatives exist.

6 out of 7 isn't so bad...and its not too off at $x=0.9$ (w/in 20%).

**Response to OP**

If you go the other way around, you would want to find a function:

$$f: f'(0)=1, \lim_{|x|\to \infty} f'(x)=0, \int |f'(x)| dx< \infty, $$

One candidate would be of the form: $f'(x)=e^{-kx^p}, p\in\{2,4,6...\}$ Unfortunately, its integral is not elementary.

Comment: Thank you very much. It suddenly something came into my mind. The same problem with $arctan$ exists here. This function cannot be shaped to my needs by simple coefficients.

Comment: @barej it met 6 exactly and 1 approximately. You may need to go piece wise if it has to equal exactly .88 at x=.9

Comment: It is true. but for better approximation, I have an idea of finding good candidate as $f'(t)$ then integrating it instead of finding $f(t)$ directly. We need a function $f'(x)$ equal to $1$ around $x=0$ and suddenly falls to near $0$ just before $x=1$. do you think it works?

Comment: @barej in principle, yes. See my edits.

Answer (score 5):

Normalizing $x$ by the $L^p$-norm of $(1, x)$ would work.
$$L^p(\vec{x}) = \sqrt[\Large p]{\sum_i|x_i|^p}$$
Your smooth saturate would then be this:
$$Sat(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt[\Large p]{1+|x|^p}}$$

As $p$ approaches infinity, you'll more closely approximate the original $Saturation$ function because $L^\infty$ is equivalent to max. Furthermore, as $p$ approaches $0$, $Sat(x)$'s second-order derivative is larger around $0$, so $Sat(x)$ will more quickly not approximate $y=x$.

Since $p$ and $x$ are real and p is positive, $Sat^\prime(x)$ is well-defined as (from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+x%2F((1%2B%7Cx%7C%5Ep)%5E(1%2Fp)))):

$$Sat^\prime(x) = \frac{1}{\left(1 + |x|^p\right)^{\large \frac{p}{p+1}}}$$

To meet your exact conditions, if you use $p\approx11.56$, then $Sat^\prime(1)\approx0.4709$ (about as good as the tanh suggested by [user76844](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1114926/136106)) and $Sat(0.9)\approx0.8800$. All higher-order derivatives should exist, but it would be generally easier to calculate them numerically.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite saturating function is tanh(x). Limits nicely at plus/minus 1. If you need more gain in the linear region, modify it as in tanh(gain*x).